# HTML file doesn't show emojis in color

Tags: html

This is a block of code from my website:

```
<a href="index.html" style="text-decoration: underline;color:rgb(20, 188, 255)"  onMouseOver="this.style.color='blue'"
onMouseOut="this.style.color='rgb(20, 188, 255)'">Home</a>
```

However, the house emoji shows as
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qRrh.png). It used to show full color till yesterday and I didn't make any changed to the file. How can I show it in full color.

Comment: This depends on the font used. Emojis are just characters in the font.

Comment: @PeterKrebs I use Comic Sans MS. But why did it suddenly stop showing emojis without making any changes? also I check the web page on a mac book and it was showing the emojis with color(apple emojis style)

Comment: Okay sure, but if there were actually *no* changes we wouldn't be able to help. So instead let's think about possible issues. Cache maybe? Maybe the webfont use actually didn't load so the browsers default font was being used and then the cache cleared and loaded the webfont or something? We'll certainly need your CSS for that as well.

Comment: Have you tried to use Css `:hover` instead of `onMouseIn` and `onMouseOut`?

Comment: @PeterKrebs There is no external css file  Its all in the html file. Also other people aren't able to see the emojis when they open the site. So its definitely on my end. Do you have any idea how do I fix it. I'm on chrome

Comment: I just don't get it, how can something break without me editing anything?

Comment: The solution is that something changed you don't know about. In any case, I didn't mean a CSS file, I meant any CSS style which lead to the Comic Sans. Please share code. Just asking yourself why doesn't change anything, help us help you. Also don't confuse the display in your IDE with the one in the browser if you use one.

Comment: @PixelPasta As you can see StackOverflow is using `Segoe UI Emoji` as the font (right click your icon in the example code given). How about using that font instead of comic sans?

Comment: @PeterKrebs I don't think that style tag could break the whole website. 
Also the pages can be found at https://pixelpasta.github.io/. You can press f12 to access the html files

Comment: It is common to paste the code here. Again: Please post the CSS as well. Your website might not be like this forever, however this question is supposed to help others in the future. Please visit the help center to learn how to ask.

Comment: sorry! I'm really new to stack overflow and this is my first question. I cant post the code here because of the limit so here's the code: https://pastebin.com/wSKq9FW8

Comment: I also tried to use Segoe UI Emoji but it's stil the same

Comment: Okay I see. Have you tried the `[<>]` button? You can create a working example directly here in StackOverflow for us to test with. I have saved your HTML as a `.html` file and opened it in the browser. The icons display colored for me. Maybe a browser issue? I hope you understand that Inline styles are hard to maintain. Better move to `<style>` tag for CSS files soon : )